# nativescript-carousel error with tns-platform-declarations

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript

I am building a nativescript carousel using the nativescript-carousel pluging but when I do tns build android I am getting this error:

node_modules/nativescript-carousel/index.d.ts(1,22): error TS6053: File 'D:/Documents/coursera_examples/nativescript/VilcabambaHotel/node_modules/nativescript-carousel/node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts' not found.

My home.component.html carousel is this:

```
    <GridLayout  horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="top" rows="*" columns="*" height="95%">        
    <Carousel #carousel ios:indicatorOffset="0,-10" ios:finite="true" ios:bounce="false" showIndicator="true" height="100%" indicatorAnimation="SWAP"
        indicatorColor="#66ccff" indicatorColorUnselected="#cceeff" height="250" width="80%">
        <CarouselItem backgroundColor="white" height="100%">
            <GridLayout *ngIf="cabin">
                <Image  [src]="BaseURL + cabin.image" ></Image>
            </GridLayout>
        </CarouselItem>
        <CarouselItem backgroundColor="white">
           <GridLayout *ngIf="house">
                <Image  [src]="BaseURL + house.image" ></Image>
            </GridLayout>
        </CarouselItem>
        <CarouselItem backgroundColor="white">
           <GridLayout *ngIf="ecoactivity">
                <Image  [src]="BaseURL + ecoactivity.image" ></Image>
            </GridLayout>
        </CarouselItem>
    </Carousel>
    </GridLayout>
```

this is my home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

//import { TNSFontIconService } from 'nativescript-ngx-fonticon';
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { View } from "ui/core/view";
import { SwipeGestureEventData, SwipeDirection } from "ui/gestures";
import * as enums from "ui/enums";

import { Cabin } from '../shared/cabin';
import { CabinService } from '../services/cabin.service';
import { House } from '../shared/house';
import { HouseService } from '../services/house.service';
import { Ecoactivity } from '../shared/ecoactivity';
import { EcoactivityService } from '../services/ecoactivity.service';
import { DrawerPage } from '../shared/drawer/drawer.page';



import { registerElement } from 'nativescript-angular/element-registry';
import { Carousel, CarouselItem } from 'nativescript-carousel';

registerElement('Carousel', () => Carousel);
registerElement('CarouselItem', () => CarouselItem);

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    // styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent extends DrawerPage implements OnInit {

    cabin: Cabin;
    house: House;
    ecoactivity: Ecoactivity;
    cabinErrMess: string;
    houseErrMess: string;
    ecoactivityErrMess: string;


    constructor(private cabinservice: CabinService,
        private houseservice: HouseService,
        private ecoactivityservice: EcoactivityService,
        private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private page: Page,
       // private fonticon: TNSFontIconService,
        @Inject('BaseURL') private BaseURL) {
        super(changeDetectorRef);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.cabinservice.getFeaturedCabin()
            .subscribe(cabin => this.cabin = cabin,
                errmess => this.cabinErrMess = <any>errmess);
        this.houseservice.getFeaturedHouse()
            .subscribe(house => this.house = house,
                errmess => this.houseErrMess = <any>errmess);
        this.ecoactivityservice.getFeaturedEcoactivity()
            .subscribe(ecoactivity => this.ecoactivity = ecoactivity,
                errmess => this.ecoactivityErrMess = <any>errmess);

    }
```

The error disapears if I remove the next lines of code but my carousel stops working

import { registerElement } from 'nativescript-angular/element-registry';
import { Carousel, CarouselItem } from 'nativescript-carousel';

registerElement('Carousel', () => Carousel);
registerElement('CarouselItem', () => CarouselItem

I created a document called reference.d.ts with the next lines of code but the error is still there.

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a improper usage of declaration within plugin, you could manually adjust it by updating the path to

```
/// <reference path="../tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
```

from

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
```

in `index.d.ts`

**Edit:**

If you still find any other TS errors, you may simply add `"skipLibCheck": true` inside `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I tried adding this to my inde.d.ts ran tns build android and still get the same error.
If I delete my reference.d.ts file I get the same error plus these 3 errors:
node_modules/nativescript-carousel/index.d.ts(45,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'android'.
node_modules/nativescript-carousel/index.d.ts(53,16): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'android'.
node_modules/nativescript-carousel/index.d.ts(56,51): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'android'.

Comment: Did you try a clean build?

Comment: Yes I have. I have done tns platform remove android then tns platform add android, deleted my node_modules and hooks and did npm install

Comment: If you delete node_modules, then you would have lost the change you did above already. Just deleting the platforms folder after modifying the above line should be good.

Comment: I added the change after I deleted node_modules. I tried doing a clean build after reinstalling node_ modules and added the above line and still get the same error

Comment: Hmm, I just had a closer look. It's not the same error. it seems to be different form the original error you had in the question. Try setting `"skipLibCheck": true,` inside `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json`.